# How to save continious data adding to local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have implemented a "Task-Board" with HTML, CSS, and JS. On the page, I have a "Save" button which each time pressed - add the new note to the page.

I want to save the new notes in the local storage and inside the "Save" button listener method. In addition, I want the note to be removed from the local storage each time the "Remove" button is pressed.

The code (without local storage implementation):

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click',function(){

var mission =
 {     
    text: document.getElementById('textarea').value,
    date: document.getElementById('date').value,
    time: document.getElementById('time').value
 };// Saving the user inputs (tasks, times, dates) 

const rows = document.getElementById('rows');// saving reference to static div (here will be inserted the new note)
const cell = document.createElement('div');
const id = document.createAttribute('id');
id.value = "div-cell";
cell.setAttributeNode(id);

cell.innerHTML = '<button id="remove-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Right 
Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><textarea> 
</textarea><div><input><input></div>'; // the new note design

const [textarea, dateinput, timeinput] = cell.querySelectorAll('textarea, input'); 
textarea.value = mission.text;
dateinput.value = mission.date;
timeinput.value = mission.time;// inserting the user input inside the new note

rows.appendChild(cell); 

cell.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){ // removing specific note
rows.removeChild(cell);
});//end "remove" button listener.
```

Do someone has an idea of how to plan the local storage (how to save many 'notes' containers and to remove a specific key in the most efficient way?)

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I would store it as a JSON string as localStorage will only accept strings, then when you need to remove it, parse it to JSON, remove the necessary entry and store it again.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to read many tutorials about local storage, but the set method of the local storage requires a key. I can't use the same key each time. so how I can generate a new key for each note and remove the key when the note is removed.

Comment: But what key should I use for each note? Maybe a keys array?

Comment: The key serves as a pointer to the data. A unique identifier for a note would be one idea. Then you could have a new key for each note. When you update a note, write over the data

Comment: But local storage is synchronous and perhaps not that performance for what you are asking it to do. Why not do in memory storage, say a plain old javascript object for the notes data, that you save to localstorage when the user directs you to or perhaps  before the user leaves the page?

Comment: The local storage is part of the work requirements